# How can I improve the best case efficiency in bubble sort? (The input is already sorted)

Tags: c, sorting

I have tried it , but I could not understand the error...

```
boolean swapped = true;
for(int j=arr.length-1; j>=0 && swapped; j--)
{
    swapped = false;
    for(int k=0; k<j; k++)
    {
        if(arr[k] > arr[k+1])
        {
            int temp = arr[k];
            arr[k] = arr[k+1];
            arr[k+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

A boolean variable ‘swapped’ determines whether any swapping has happened in a
particular iteration, if no swapping has occurred, then the given array is sorted and no
more iterations are required.

Comment: C does not have a bool type or knows what "true" is

Comment: This looks like a java code based on the line `boolean swapped = true;` and `arr.length`. C doesn't have boolean type as @MoritzSchmidt mentioned and array in C doesn't have property `length`.

Comment: But C does have a `bool` type which takes the values `true` or `false`. You `#include <stdbool.h>`. You have to add the line `swapped = true;` in the code block that swaps the values.

Comment: @WeatherVane   Yes , I have included <stdbool.h> , but, it is not working...

Comment: But did you add the other part of my comment?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt thank you for the edit , as I am new here , I don't know all the features available here.   

But, If we use the header file <stdbool.h> , we can use boolean datatype...

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes!!!! That works.  After adding  swaaped = true , it works . And I also understood my logical error....... Thank You , For the answer..... I will provide it in the answer section with your name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WeatherVane gave this answer in the comment box...

Here ,I am providing the code---

```
boolean swapped = true;
for(int j=arr.length-1; j>=0 && swapped; j--)
   {
     swapped = false;
     for(int k=0; k<j; k++)
       {
        if(arr[k] > arr[k+1])
           {
            int temp = arr[k];
            arr[k] = arr[k+1];
            arr[k+1] = temp;
            **swapped = true;**
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you initialize swapped as true, to then for each iteration set it as false?

Comment: Because , if not swapped , then the loop will terminate after 1st iteration of the outermost loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, your code seems to be Java code instead of C. C and Java syntax are pretty similar but there are some differences. One is that the C doesn't have boolean type by default and you have to include the header `stdbool.h` as mentioned by @Weather Vane. Make sure you change `boolean` type to `bool` to adhere with C syntax:

```
bool swapped = true;
```

Another thing is that C array doesn't have property `length` like in Java array. You can get an array length in C using the function `sizeof` instead:

```
size_t arr_length =  sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

**Update:**  As @Weather Vane mentioned in the comment, make sure you initialize the array and get its length inside the same function for the `sizeof` function to work properly. If you pass the array into a function, you can't get its length by using `sizeof` because that will only have the size of the pointer `int *` instead of the array `int []`.

Comment: If we include the header file <stdbool.h> , we can use boolean datatype, thanks.

Comment: You can't find the length that way from a function argument. You must explicitly pass the length as another argument.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're right. I've updated my answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: Don't use sizeof to determine the string's length, use the strlen function form the standard library.

Comment: @Leo Did OP mention `arr` is a character array type?

Comment: True he didn't, but there is something certain is that calculating the size any type of array in C like that will cause compatibility issues, am only trying to make him aim his interest into the C standard library, you can easily see that ANY function in there that takes an array will also take the size of the array.

Comment: @Leo `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is method that is documented in the  "The C Programming Language" by Dennis Ritchie, who invented C programming language (2n Edition Section 6.3 Page 135) so I'm pretty sure there won't be any compatibility issues :) Another thing is that it works for all types of array not just character or integer array.

Comment: I've had a love and hate relationship with that book, i keep asking myself why would the whole GNU project wouldn't use the sizeof trick. Why wouldnt them even check if array was null in the base strlen implementation.

Comment: @Leo They did actually. Here's one of their repositories https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils. A grep search showed that they used `sizeof` method  in `./src/tac-pipe.c:115`, `./src/factor.c:68` and several more. As for why they use `strlen`, they used it because it is more convenient the get the number of characters in the string when you know for sure the variable is a character array. When using `sizeof`, you have to minus 1 for the null pointer.

Comment: Yes .I Got it .